# Why aren't dynamically generated input fields added to the $_POST array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I have a form where user can create list puncts, which he wants to add dynamically. But these added puncts for some reason aren't added to the $_POST array in php.

Error:

> Undefined index: lis

js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnzs97ga/18/

JavaScript:

```
  $(function() {
    let amountLi = 0;
    let increased;
    $("#amountLi").change(function() {
        if (amountLi <= (Number)($("#amountLi").val())) {
            increased = true;
        }
        else {
            increased = false;
        }
        amountLi = (Number)($("#amountLi").val());
    });

    $("#create_list_items").click(function() {
        if ($(".input-area-lis").length == 0) {
            $("#liGenerate").after(`<div class="input-area-lis" id="lis"></div>`);
        }
        
        let lis = $("#lis");
        let liOnPage = lis.children(".li").length;
        if (increased == true) {
            for (let i = liOnPage; i < amountLi; i++) {
                lis.append(`<div class="li">
                    <label>Punct №${i + 1}</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lis[]">
                </div>`);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (let i = liOnPage - 1; i >= amountLi; i--) {
                console.log(lis.children(".li").eq(i));
                lis.children(".li").eq(i).remove();
            }
        }
        
    });
})
```

PHP:

```
$lis = $_POST["lis"]; // Error
```

**UPD: More context about new_album.php**
There's basically no more context about new_album.php, all I can attach here is this:

```
        var_dump($_POST);
        var_dump($lis);
        $name = htmlentities($_POST["name"]);
        $size = $_POST["size"];;
        foreach ($size as $elem) {
            $elem = htmlentities($elem);
        }
        $cost = htmlentities($_POST["cost"]);
        $lis = $_POST["lis"];
        foreach ($lis as $li) {
            $li = htmlentities($li);
        }
```

var_dump($_POST) gives:

```
array (size=3)
  'name' => string 'Album1' (length=6)
  'size' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '20' (length=2)
      1 => string '30' (length=2)
  'cost' => string '2000' (length=4)
```

var_dump($lis) gives: null

Comment: Unable to reproduce. It all seems fine. How are you submitting the form, regularly or through some JS?

Comment: your code work, do `print_r($lis);`

Comment: @El_Vanja if you see the code in fiddle is normal submit

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes, in the fiddle. But the fiddle might be a reduced example, that's why I ask.

Comment: If it's a normal submit, then we'd need more context about the `new_album.php` script.

Comment: Try it without `enctype="multipart/form-data"`...that's only needed if you're uploading files. Shouldn't make any difference, but...

Comment: Also, you say `// Error`...but is there an actual error message? If so share please. If not, please explain exactly what you mean. What does `var_dump($_POST);` show, if you output that?

Comment: @ADyson I believe that "error" is actually the "Undefined index" notice mentioned earlier in the question.

Comment: @El_Vanja doh, somehow I failed to see that. Thanks.

Comment: @El_Vanja I'm submitting the form regularly

Comment: @El_Vanja I added some more context

Comment: @ADyson in my real project there's a file uploading, so it's not an option for me to do so

Comment: `var_dump($lis)` is likely null because you run it before $lis is defined. But regardless, there seems to be no "lis" in var_dump($_POST); ...which doesn't fit with the client-side code you've shown. Look in your browser's Network tab when you're submitting the form (make sure Preserve Log is on so you can still see the POST request). See what's actually being submitted. The JS you've shown here doesn't appear to reproduce the problem you're showing in the PHP. It's all a bit confusing.

Comment: When I look at the fiddle, I don't see a form element with the name `size`, which is present in the `$_POST`. This tells me that the fiddle has been modified to some extent (probably to make it simple), but since the fiddle's code doesn't reproduce the issue, maybe some crucial bit was left out. Try reducing your actual code down to the one in the fiddle and then add the differences one by one. Maybe that way you can identify the culprit.

Comment: I don't really know how but the bug has been fixed. I just commented all lines of code that weren't in js Fiddle example, and then started testing how it works and steb by step uncommenting parts of code, and everything works fine now.

Comment: I have a guess that the error was because of that I was submitting the form, getting the info on the web page in new_album.php, and then was returning to the form page from new_album.php and was trying to submit it again, but once when the bug has already been fixed, I paid attention to the fact that list puncts were deleted from the form, and when I clicked submit that time, I got the error. So I think that's the only explanation to that mystery

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'd love to click +1 to all of your comments, but I must have at least 50 rep to do that